# Wifi on Linux Mint 19.3 with Intel wireless card stops working after a while

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi, iwlwifi

I recently installed Linux Mint 19.3, and the wifi works for a while after starting the computer up. But after some time, usually a couple hours of continued use, the wireless functionality just stops working, and the only way to get it working again is to do a complete restart.

Relevant system info from inxi:

```
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless 3160 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: e000 
  bus ID: 02:00.0 
  IF: wlp2s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet vendor: Dell 
  driver: r8169 v: kernel port: d000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
  IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
```

Running iwconfig yields:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Additional info/things I've already tried:

- Wired internet works just fine.
- Restarting NetworkManager doesn't help, even after logging out and then back in. The only thing it changes is that both my network applet and inxi list wireless as up until I reset, at which point the state is down and the network applet says wireless is unavailable.
- I've tried switching kernel versions, specifically to 5.0.0-37, 5.0.0-32, and 4.15.0-72 - the issue persists on all of them.
- Nothing is getting blocked with rfkill (except Bluetooth, which I have turned off):

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

- I've added the following to iwlwifi.conf to no avail:

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8
options iwlwifi power_save=0
```

- The firmware drivers I have installed for my card are:

```
iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-14.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-16.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
```

(I tried installing 14 myself, but I assume it's not getting used since it's not the highest version number)

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to answer, but may help others. I can't help with troubleshooting, but I had the same symptoms on a Fujitsu Laptop a couple of years ago, and resolved completely by changing from Network Manager to WICD. That was mint 18.3 XFCE. Available from std repo. Google instructions for permanently disabling NM.

I have since sorted another Fujitsu Laptop which was spamming logs to death by doing the same. Mint 19.3 XFCE.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. If you found instructions for disabling `nm` that you found useful, maybe you could add a link to that page (and possibly summarize the necessary steps in your answer, as external links can become invalid or their content chang).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in LM19.3. I've just installed WICD. It's working now and we'll see what happens.
I disabled the startup of NM in the  Control Center Startup Applications. WICD was automatically added and enabled there.